# No such module error when importing Swift custom framework

Tags: xcode, swift-custom-framework

I have a large and old Xcode project with a lot of mixed Objective C/Swift code.

On wanting to add an iMessages extension I found I have to start with a framework to share code between the app and the extension.

I tested this in a new project by following [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial) and everything worked great

When trying this in my old Xcode project, I get to the import stage in my application's code to import my custom framework but get a `No such module ...` error. I've ran through everything multiple times checking all imports for the custom framework with no luck.

A lot of build settings have been customised over the years this project has been added to and my guess is that this is the issue?

Can anyone recommend any Build Settings in the Xcode project I might want to double check? Nothing seems out of the ordinary but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Update... Manually adding the framework path to `Framework Search Paths` allows the project to build. The path is retrieved from the app's build report under the framework's build target. Notably this path is a `release-iphonesimulator` path

Comment: Update... We have custom build configurations in the Xcode project. When comparing my test project with the real one, the test project builds the `.framework` in the same directory as the `.app` (`Debug-iphonesimulator`) as oppose to the "real" project which builds the `.framework` to `Debug-iphonesimulator` folder but the `.app` is built in the `MyBuildConfiguration-iphonesimulator` folder